# Unknown provider error when injecting factory

Tags: mongodb, angularjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am using yeoman angular full stack generator. Trying out ToDo items tutorial with MongoDB.
Everything worked fine i.e. I was able to read from DB using  $http.get. However I decided to go further and create a factory so I can perform CURD.

After creating factory I tried to inject it but getting error as follows:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: factToDoProvider <- factToDo
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$injector/unpr?p0=factToDoProvider%20%3C-NaNactToDo
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3538:19
at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3665:39)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3543:45
at getService (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3665:39)
at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3687:13)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3708:23)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6758:28
at link (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:897:26)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6212:13)
```

Main.js controller looks like

```
'use strict';

angular.module('angularFsApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, factToDo) {
    $http.get('/api/awesomeThings').success(function(awesomeThings) {
      $scope.awesomeThings = awesomeThings;
    });

    $http.get('/todo/todoItems').success(function(todoItems) {
      $scope.todoItems = todoItems;
    });
    //$scope.newtodoItems = factToDo.getAllItems();

   });
```

Where factToDo is my factory which look like as follows (todo.js)

```
angular.module('angularFsApp')
.factory('factToDo', function() {
    return {
        getAllItems: function () {
            return [
                {description: 'Hello World 1', priority: '15'},
                {description: 'Hello World 2', priority: '15'},
                {description: 'Love for all', priority: '1500'}
            ];
            }
    }
});
```

I tried by changing my code in main.js as described in [AngularJS error ref](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector%3aunpr?p0=factToDoProvider) as follows

```
angular.module('angularFsApp')
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'factToDo', function ($scope, $http, factToDo) {
```

as well as  I tried [Dan Wahlin](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/08/16/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service.aspx) but i got same issue.

Comment: Do you include a js file were the 'factToDo' is defined ?

Comment: @IgorMalyk Thanks that was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the file with the 'factToDo' is included into your app.

For a convenient development and to avoid issues like this in the future try the [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) task runner to concatenate all your code for you and include it as a one file.

[This tutorial](http://tamas.io/introduction-to-grunt/) seems to be sufficient for starting with Grunt and file concatenation.